# Can two different PSN profiles be accessed by a single ps3 user?

Tags: mass-effect-3, mass-effect-series

I have a UK PlayStation Store account, I live in Ireland. However, just found out my Mass Effect Trilogy boxset is US region, so the UK DLC isn't compatible. Rage! I am wondering is it possible to set up a fake US account to download the DLC, or is the fact that my profile is linked to a UK account make this impossible? Should I make another profile on my PS3 system specifically to play the Mass Effect games and link THAT profile to the US account? Any help would be really appreciated.